# PHP verify if every $array[$key] is not empty

Tags: php

So, i have this code that seems to be doing the mechanical work correctly, avoiding to write on tables if one or more fields from a form are left empty, but the echos and messages aren't working as they supposed to:

SOLUTION TO THE PROBLEM:
I don't believe this will be useful to anyone, but just for the record, the solution is simple:

```
$campos = array('nome','morada','email','telemovel','codigopostal','vat');
foreach ($campos as $key => $campo) {
    $campos[$key] = $_GET[$campo];
    if(!isset($_GET[$campo])|| empty($_GET[$campo])){
                header("Location: ../index.php?erro=".$campo);
                $verifica=FALSE;
                die();
            }else{
                $verifica=TRUE;
            }
}
```

This will give me some problems, not what i really wanted but solves the logical problems i was having. Thanks to you all guys.

```
$campos = array('nome','morada','email','telemovel','codigopostal','vat');
foreach ($campos as $key => $campo) {
    $campos[$key] = ($_GET[$campo]);
    while(list($key, $campo)= each($campos))
            if(!isset($_GET[$campo])|| $_GET[$campo]==""){
                echo("não preencheu um dos campos");
                $verifica = FALSE;
                die();
            }else{
        echo $_GET[$campo]." \r\n";}
        $verifica = TRUE;
}

if($verifica==TRUE){
some irrelevant code.
}
```

As i said, the code itself is working flawlessly, BUT if i only left 2 empty fields on the form, the echo $_GET[$campo] will be working even though the variable $verifica will be set as FALSE

AN HINT:

One of the fields is making the code to fail, is the second one, so, if i do this:

```
../phcexport.php?nome=myname&morada=&codigopostal=postcode&email=@.com&vat=12312­3&telemovel=00800
```

And ignore the second value from the array, the code will work like a charm, i can try as many combinations as i can as long as i left the second field empty, it will work properly, giving me the error "some field is empty", in this case i know it is, the "morada" is empty, and if i fill it in the code says "its ok, all filled in" BUT the "morada" should be the last to be filled so the code works. Funny... (I'm sorry about all the text to describe the problem, i'm Portuguese)

EDIT2: For the rest of the code i need to use $campos[$key], so attribute a key to the arrays is essencial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you reset `$verifica` in the `else`. So regardless if you set it once to `FALSE`, the last foreach iteration will determine the outcome. But you can "simplify" the whole approach to:

```
$verify = array_search(0, array_map("strlen", $campos)) === false;
```

This simply checks for the string length of each array entry. If none of them is `0`, then the expression will return `true` for `$verify`;

Comment: I will try your solution mario, thank you very much. Can you just tell me why the second value from the array is causing the problem? I am in the proccess of learning and it would be good if you could tell me, if i ignore this field and left it empty, the code will work: ../phcexport.php?nome=myname&morada=&codigopostal=postcode&email=@.com&vat=123123&telemovel=00800

Comment: @Souza: I don't believe it is the second entry. After a second look you are using **two iterators** actually. The `foreach` conflicts with the `while =each()`. It's certainly some logic error, not a problem with the array values.

Comment: No, of course it's not the field or the array, but it was just a hint to get to the origin of the problem :P. I will take a look, probably some logic error as you said.

Answer (score 1):

instead of doing `$_GET[$campo]==""`, you can maybe use the [empty](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function :

```
empty($_GET[$campo])
```

This should address all problems related to different data types.

Your also maybe running in a problem because you're using a variable named `$campo` in two different loops, try changing the variable name in the while loop to see if it works better.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Krtek, i noticed something very weird now, the only field that is causing a malfunction is the second one, "morada", when this field is left empty, the code works as it should be, if i enter some value on it, it makes the echos work in a weird way. I will try to change the variable you mentioned, brb. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Check the exact value of $campo that is causing the incorrect behaviour, then consult this table to make sure you are using the right kind of comparison

http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose

Comment: the exact value of $campo that is giving me a hard time is "morada", it's making the code not work as it should.

Answer (score 1):

try following solution, empty fields can not pass the test

```
<?php
$campos = array('nome', 'morada', 'email', 'telemovel', 'codigopostal', 'vat');
$verifica = TRUE;
foreach ($campos as $campo) {
    if (!isset($_GET[$campo]) || empty($_GET[$campo])) {
        echo "não preencheu um dos campos" ;
        $verifica = FALSE;
        break;
    } else {
        echo $_GET[$campo] ."\r\n";
    }
}

if ($verifica == TRUE) {
//  some irrelevant code.
} else {
    die();
}
```

Comment: There is one problem, you are not attributing any keys to the arrays, on the code i will be using $campos[2] , $campos[3] , $campos[5] , $campos[7] to get my values.

Comment: you did not mention any thing about this in your question, why don't you use $campos['nome'] to get your values? that's more friendly for us.